Is there a way to tell at runtime whether a Java final field is a constant?
I'd like to be able to differentiate at runtime (presumably using reflection), between these two cases, where the former has a final field defined at initialization (i.e. a constant), and the latter defines it through the constructor.
class MyClass {
    
    final int value = 42;
    
    public MyClass() {
    }

}

class MyClass {
    
    final int value;
    
    public MyClass() {
        value = 42;
    }

}

I've tried doing this by examining the Field's access flags and modifiers, but have not found anything relevant.
Is there a way to do this?

No there isn't.  But why does it matter?  The two cases are not semantically distinguishable.  (Calling one constant and the other not constant doesn't make sense.)

Looking at the provided answers I'd conclude there is a difference but reflection cannot spot it. You'd have to analyze bytecode directly. Which again might be implementation dependent.

Why do you want to check something at runtime that you already know at compile time? Why do you want to differentiate at all?

It's because I've found that reflectively setting a field that is actually a constant (i.e. the first case) does not work; it silently fails and does not actually set the specified value. I want to be able to detect this before even trying so that I can make it an error condition.

I just discovered that the field actually IS being set, but an expression that uses the field in toString() does not change, presumably because the initial field value was baked in as a constant at compile time.

Changing a final field can cause problems in general. But having an instance field that is a compile-time constant should be a rare corner case, as there is not much use in wasting heap memory per object, to hold a constant value which is even inlined at every use site.

We can investigate this by disassembling the class file. If we compile
public class Test {
    
    final int foo = 42;
    
    final int bar;
    
    Test() {
        bar = 42;
    }
}

and then disassemble it with javap -v Test.class, we get:
  final int foo;
    descriptor: I
    flags: (0x0010) ACC_FINAL
    ConstantValue: int 42

  final int bar;
    descriptor: I
    flags: (0x0010) ACC_FINAL

  stackoverflow.Test();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: (0x0000)
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #13                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: bipush        42
         7: putfield      #15                 // Field foo:I
        10: aload_0
        11: bipush        42
        13: putfield      #17                 // Field bar:I
        16: return

As you can see, the information you seek is present in the ConstantValue attribute for use by the Java compiler. However, this attribute serves no purpose at runtime (the field value is set through putfield irrespective of whether the value is constant), so the runtime does not read this information when it loads a class, and doesn't expose it through reflection. You would therefore need to parse the class file yourself, for instance using the new class file API introduced as a preview feature in JDK 22, or any other class file library.
Note that this assumes the field to be declared final, and its value to be a compile time constant expression.

there is also a difference if using these variables: using foo will be inlined (bipush 42), while using bar will actually access the field

The ConstantValue is required for the Java Compiler, as this inlining also happens if you compile an other class against this which accesses the field directly.

No.  One is just syntactic sugar for the other, so there's no actual difference at runtime that reflection can identify.

I believe they are different.  The first one will be treated as a constant by the compiler, and used directly like a literal with no reference to the field or the class itself.  I don't know if that's detectable in any way by the code however.  (It might be by the build system.)

Ah ... that's a different distinction: constant versus compile-time constant.

That requires several things to be true: directly initialized, static final, and a primitive or String.  That seems to go well beyond the OP's expectations.

@LouisWasserman compile-time constants do not need to be static, only final. In other words, instance fields and even local variables can be compile-time constants.
